# Hash keys get converted to int automatically?

Tags: javascript, json

JavaScript console snippet:

```
> obj = {"1": "Hello, World", "2": "Goodbye, World"};
> obj[1]
  "Hello, World"
> obj["1"]
  "Hello, World"
```

So, for some reason, if you have keys that can be converted to an integer, the corresponding values can be accessed using the integer as well. This is very useful: I'm fetching a JSON over Ajax and, in JSON, it's not legal to have ints as hash keys (or at least Python's JSON serializer thinks so). However, I need to access them as ints, which is why I want to know:

1. Why is this happening?
2. Is it reliable? (I can see it's working on Chrome and Firefox, which is enough for my app, but I wouldn't want it to be some common bug that will get fixed in the next version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All properties of JavaScript objects are strings. Note this behavior:

```
var foo = {};
foo[foo] = "hello";
console.log( foo["[object Object]"] );
//-> "hello"

foo.toString = function(){ return "sassy" };
foo.sassy = "Oh yes!";
console.log( foo[foo] );
//-> "Oh yes!"
```

So, when you set or get `foo[1]` you are actually setting/getting `foo[1.toString()]`. Yes, this is reliable.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript **loves** transforming your numbers into strings. Whenever it can, it will. Check the type conversion rules.

This might help:
http://united-coders.com/matthias-reuter/all-about-types-in-javascript-automatic-type-conversion

Edit -- fun fact:

```
>>> "3" + "5"
"35"
>>> "3" - "2"
1
```

Comment: Correct, but not an argument for the issue at hand. See Phrogz's anwer to understand why.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say your keys are converted to ints. I would say `toString()` is called on your 'accessor' (the key you use in obj[1]), because it is expected to be a string.

Answer (score -1):

1 and "1" mean pretty much the same thing in a loosely typed language like javascript (remember that JSON is javascript object notation).